# AWS CDK y AWS CodePipeline

Tags: typescript, aws, pipeline

estoy creando una infraestructura en AWS con una tabla Dynamo y algunas lambdas a modo de "pseudo CRUD". Simplemente permiten añadir registros, eliminar, consultar, etc (no incluyo todas puesto que no tienen relación con el problema y así es más sencillo leer el código).

Sin embargo, al añadir el código para AWS CodePipeline tengo el siguiente error:

```
[Container] 2023/05/23 13:00:26 Command did not exit successfully npx cdk synth exit status 1
[Container] 2023/05/23 13:00:26 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2023/05/23 13:00:26 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: npx cdk synth. Reason: exit status 1
```

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo? Estoy bastante desorientado. El código que estoy usando es:

```
//Librerías utilizadas
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as dynamodb from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-dynamodb";
import * as lambda from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda";
import * as apigw from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigateway";
import * as path from 'path';
import { CodePipeline, CodePipelineSource, ShellStep } from "aws-cdk-lib/pipelines";
import { ManualApprovalStep } from 'aws-cdk-lib/pipelines';

export class MicroserviciosStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    //Definición de la tabla Dynamodb
    const tablaRegistros = new dynamodb.Table(this, "TablaRegistros", {
      partitionKey: { name: "id", type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING },
      removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
    });

    //Definición de funciones lambda
    const nuevoRegistroFunction = new lambda.Function(this, "NuevoRegistroFunction", {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
      handler: 'handler.nuevoRegistro', 
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.resolve(__dirname, 'lambda')),
      environment: {
        TABLA_REGISTROS: tablaRegistros.tableName,
      },
    });

    //Permisos para las diferentes funciones lambda
    tablaRegistros.grantReadWriteData(nuevoRegistroFunction);

    //Creación de API Gateway
    const registrosAPI = new apigw.RestApi(this, "RegistrosApi");

    //Implementación de funciones en el endpoint
    registrosAPI.root
      .resourceForPath("registros")
      .addMethod("PUT", new apigw.LambdaIntegration(nuevoRegistroFunction))
  
    new CodePipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
      pipelineName: 'TestPipeline',
      synth: new ShellStep('Synth', {
        input: CodePipelineSource.gitHub('ivozmediano/microservicios', 'main'),
        commands: [
                    'npm ci',
                    'npm run build',
                    'npx cdk synth',
                  ]
      }),
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Pues el error se produce al ejecutar la línea `npx cdk synth` ... sería conveniente probar esos comandos de forma local (quizás montarte un docker con nodejs 14 para emular el entorno de codepipeline lo más fielmente posible). De esta forma puedes hacer pruebas más fácilmente y ahorrarás tiempo y dinero

Answer (score 0):

El error que estás obteniendo indica que el comando npx cdk synth falló durante la fase de construcción (BUILD) de tu pipeline. Este comando es responsable de sintetizar tu aplicación CDK en una plantilla de CloudFormation.

Aunque el mensaje de error no proporciona detalles específicos sobre qué podría estar mal, hay algunas cosas que podrías intentar:

**Problemas de dependencias**: Asegúrate de que todas las dependencias estén correctamente instaladas y sean compatibles entre sí. Puedes hacer esto ejecutando npm ci localmente para instalar las dependencias de tu proyecto tal como están definidas en tu archivo package-lock.json. Luego, intenta ejecutar npx cdk synth para ver si el problema persiste.

**Errores de sintaxis o de tipo**: Revisa tu código para asegurarte de que no haya errores de sintaxis o de tipo que puedan estar causando que el comando cdk synth falle.

**Falta de permisos**: Asegúrate de que la cuenta de AWS y el rol que estás utilizando para ejecutar la pipeline de CodePipeline tengan los permisos necesarios para ejecutar todas las acciones que has definido en tu aplicación CDK.

**Depuración del error**: Intenta agregar más información de depuración a tu pipeline para ayudar a identificar el problema. Podrías, por ejemplo, intentar ejecutar npx cdk synth con la opción --debug para obtener más información sobre qué podría estar fallando.

Finalmente, si nada de lo anterior te ayuda a identificar el problema, podrías intentar ejecutar npx cdk synth en tu entorno local para ver si puedes reproducir el error. Si puedes reproducir el error localmente, esto podría facilitarte la depuración y te permitiría probar posibles soluciones más rápidamente.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. El problema es que en local no salta ningún error, el comando npx cdk synth se puede ejecutar sin problema. El problema surge cuando despliego el código y AWS CodePipeline hace su "función", ahí es cuando salta el error.

Comment: Asegúrate de [no utilizar ChatGPT](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5462): está prohibido aquí.